# Make Off-Canvas sidebar width 100% for mobile using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a bootstrap web site and I have an off-canvas sidebar that I have being pushed in to view and pushes back out when selecting the close icon. It is working okay, but I need to find a way to make it to where it will be 100% width for mobile view. The way the sidebar works, I am unable to do this with just css using media queries because it is using JavaScript to style the width of the side bar when opened. I currently have it set to have a width of 45% when opened, which is what I need for desktop view. However, at mobile view it needs to expand the full width (100%) as the 45% width at that mobile size is not enough. I am new to JS, so I am unsure how to do this with JS. Is there a way to use JS to set the width at a specific resolution breakpoint?

Thanks for any help.

Below is my code:
HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Button to open side menu</h2>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

JS:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "45%";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "45%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is not trying to manipulate CSS using JavaScript directly. Instead of setting the width to "45%" or "0", you can set classNames:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").className = "sidenav open";
    document.getElementById("main").className = "open";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").className = "sidenav";
    document.getElementById("main").className = "";
}
```

And add these CSS:

```
#mySidenav {
  width: 0;
}

#main {
  marginLeft: 0;
}

#mySidenav.open {
  width: 45%;
}

#main.open {
  marginRight: 45%;
}

/* on mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  #mySidenav.open { width: 100%; }
  #main.open { marginRight: 100%; }
}
```

Hope it will help.